# Sketch the region in the complex plane

Tags: complex-numbers

$$\operatorname{Im}\left(\frac{z+2}{z-2}\right)\ge 1$$

Not sure how to sketch such a region.

I tried
$$\operatorname{Im}({z+2})\ge\operatorname{Im}({z-2})$$

That comes out to $ 1 \ge  1$

I tried $$\operatorname{Im}({z+2})(z-2)^{-1}\ge 1 $$

Comment: Note that in general $Im(z/w)\not=Im(z)/Im(w)$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If $z=a+bi$, with $a,b\in\Bbb R$, then\begin{align}\operatorname{Im}\left(\frac{z+2}{z-2}\right)\geqslant1&\iff\operatorname{Im}\left(\frac{a+2+bi}{a-2+bi}\right)\geqslant1\\&\iff\operatorname{Im}\left(\frac{(a+2+bi)(a-2-bi)}{(a-2+bi)(a-2-bi)}\right)\geqslant1\\&\iff\operatorname{Im}\left(\frac{a^2+b^2-4bi}{(a-2)^2+b^2}\right)\geqslant1\\&\iff\frac{-4b}{(a-2)^2+b^2}\geqslant1\\&\iff-4b\geqslant(a-2)^2+b^2\\&\iff4\geqslant(a-2)^2+(b+2)^2.\end{align}The final inequality describes the closed disk centered at $2-2i$ with radius $2$ (minus the point $2$, for which the expression $\operatorname{Im}\left(\frac{z+2}{z-2}\right)$ is undefined).

Comment: Thank you sir, the confusion lay with the added real values

Comment: I'm glad I could help.

Comment: @mathlove Indeed. I've edited my answer. Thank you.